# How to find Jira tasks with all sub-tasks 'done'

Tags: jira, jql

I want to use Jira Query Language to find the tasks which all their sub-tasks are in 'done' state.
Which query can I use for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
issuetype in subTaskIssueTypes() AND status = Done
```

A simple way to do this is use the Basic search query and then switch to the Advanced view. Jira will auto fill in the JQL in the text box.

The URL for the above JQL is:

https://jira-domain-com/issues/?jql=issuetype%20in%20subTaskIssueTypes()%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Done

EDIT:

Yes I misunderstood your question. But now that I understand, I see that it is a near duplicate of this one: [Find parents issues which contains subtasks with label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136900/find-parents-issues-which-contains-subtasks-with-label)

As @strantheman said, ScriptRunner allows you to do this:

```
issueFunction in parentsOf("status = Done")
```

Additionally you could use the REST API - get a list of all tasks and sub tasks and check if the subtasks are all done. But this will be quite a bit of coding.

Comment: I think it is misunderstood. I want to find all **tasks** which all theirs sub-tasks are done.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the Script Runner plugin and the linkedIssuesOf function.

issueFunction in parentsOf("status = Done")

Answer (score 0):

you can add a quick filter. ( MyPro = your project name)

```
status = "In progress" AND subTasksCount > 0 AND project = MyPro AND subTaskStatus not in ("In progress", "To Do")
```