# Jira Querying Epic By Issue Custom Attribute

Tags: jira, jira-agile

**Background**

I have created a custom attribute in Jira, say "MyAttribue", and I have set on various issues in jira. For my kanban board, I made a simple query to pull in all issues with this type, MyAttribue = "MyValue", and set the board to set swimlanes by epic, as that's a useful grouping for our tasks. This was working fine, until an epic needed to have a different value set to MyAttribute other than MyValue. When this changed, all issues in the epic disappeared from my board because their epic no longer met the requirements of the board.

**Question**

Is there a way to word the query that will allow it to pull in all tickets with MyAttribue = "MyValue", but also pull any epics that have any children also matching this criteria?

Comment: Have you looked into [parentsOf()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136900/find-parents-issues-which-contains-subtasks-with-label) function?

Comment: Have you got the Script Runner plugin?